# Is there a PHP script to mail forms for beginners for free?

Tags: php, mailer

I have a place where I want users to submit emails for newsletter subs and a place to submit an entire contact form. Zero php knowledge outside of know that it can do what I need.

Comment: php can't do what you need, YOU can do what you need with php.

Comment: @Byron, in this case that's not true. PHP has a mail function. :)

Comment: @incrediman: yes, but you need to tell the mail() function who and what to mail ;-)

Comment: If you have no knowledge of PHP whatsoever, how do you expect to get the script up and running and how is the question programming-related then?

Comment: Joking aside, Byron and Josh are both totally right (and Gordon as well). If you don't know what you're doing at all, it really doesn't matter how many neat features are packed into the language and its libraries. Period.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out [FormToEmail](http://formtoemail.com/). From their site:

> FormToEmail is a PHP form mail script.
>   It comes in a free version and a Pro
>   version. It processes web forms and
>   sends the contents of the form to you
>   by email. It will process any form. It
>   doesn't make forms but it comes with
>   HTML code for a basic contact form
>   that you can use on your website. It
>   is very secure and cannot be hijacked
>   by spammers. It is very simple to
>   install, you only need to add your
>   email address to it. Step-by-step
>   instructions written in plain English.

Answer (score 2):

There's a mail function built-in, take a look at

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

you will however, need to format the email body with the form data posted, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you don't need to do any php programming to create a such a setup. There are plenty of mailing list software apps available and you can grab a formmail script (like the one from [Matt's Script Archive](http://www.scriptarchive.com/formmail.html)) and build the html with the right fields.

Comment: What's the saying: good coders imitate, great coders steal? :) (see http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2004/12/never-design-what-you-can-steal.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use the mail function.

However be aware that *you need to specify the correct headers yourself* if you want to use html in your emails!

A common beginner's mistake is assuming you can simply use html tags with mail and it should work automatically.

Figured this was worth mentioning, since you are wanting to do a newsletter. If you try sending the email, and the raw html tags seem to appear in the message, this is your issue :)

Answer (score 0):

As someone who is a PHP know-nothing, I often look for easy solutions to complex problems. Using a super simple PHP form can have some downsides such as getting massive amounts of spam if you don't have any measures to prevent that, setting up those measures is hard to do if you do not have any knowledge of PHP.

Here is what I found, there is a script here: http://www.dagondesign.com/articles/secure-php-form-mailer-script/
that you can download at no charge and the developer seems to have a lot guidance on how to install and use. I was able to set it up and get it to work.. not without having to spend quite of bit of time reading and trouble shooting. Hope that helps you.